# fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees

Tags: git, git-svn, corruption, msysgit

I'm trying to import a large subversion repository into git using git-svn (so that I can work in git but still dcommit to subversion from time to time). After importing more than 4000 revisions I'm now getting the following error whenever I run `git svn fetch` or `git svn rebase`, which I don't manage to get rid of:

```
$ git svn fetch
error: invalid object 100644 1f2....742 for 'src/path/.../file.cs'
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
write-tree: command returned error: 128
```

What I've tried so far:

- `git fsck --full` doesn't report anything, neither does `git fsck --unreachable` or `git fsck --no-reflog`
- `git gc --aggressive` doesn't help
- moving the single pack file away and reimporting it with `git unpack-objects` doesn't help
- `git svn reset -rXY` with XY a bit lower than the latest imported revsion doesn't seem to help either, neither does manually removing the latest entries from the `reflog` up to XY.
- reboot. Sounds silly, but I did observe some weird issues while importing the first ~4000 revision, as if something was leaking a lot of kernel resources (most likely in windows subsystem), might be related to msys/mingw (or the avira virus scanner, which I disabled for testing).

I also didn't find out what error 128 really stands for. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338164/fatal-error-unpacking-a-tree-object-during-a-git-svn-fetch) which is about error 128 as well but with different error messages, and without a solution.

msysgit version `1.6.4.msysgit.0` with bash on xp sp3

Comment: Ask on git mailing list (git@vger.kernel.org), you don't need to subscribe to post (and there are a few web interfaces to read it, including Gmane and MARC)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`git svn gc`

(possibly `git gc` and `git prune` before)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Don't know if gc/prune were necessary, I do them as a matter of course.

Comment: I had this problem. Running just `git svn gc` without `git gc` and `git prune` fixed it for me.

Comment: `git gc` fixed this issue for me, while `git svn gc` is not yet possible on msysgit

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:  Try resolving any merge conflicts, committing them, and they fetch/pull again.

Longer explanation:
I'm guessing you resolved this issue, since it was posted so long ago.  I'm writing this since Google's ranking of StackOverflow articles is high enough that other people with this problem would be very likely to visit this page if they had this error.

I encountered a similar error when trying to do a "git stash", what turned out to be the problem was that a merge conflict had occurred after a pull.   I had not resolved & committed the conflict, and this left the repository in a state that prevented me from pulling/merging/etc...

If you make sure you don't have any blocking files, try again.

Good luck!